# setLabel in JqGrid is not working

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am new to JqGrid. I want to change the column name after the grid loads. I have tried

```
$("#Gridname).jqGrid("setLabel","FirstName","Modifed FistName",{"text-align":"right"});
```

but it is not working.

Comment: "but it is not working" is not very descriptive. Please try to debug your problem (i.e. see if `$("#Gridname)` returns any items) to give more specific infromation in your question. Showing 2-3 lines of relevant HTML could be useful too. Note: there is no need to add "thank you notes" to the question, please upvote/accept useful answers instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your code inside of a window.setTimeout so that it runs after the grid has been created:

This is what I used to change my jqGrid column headers:

```
$(function () {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        $("#Gridname).jqGrid("setLabel","FirstName","Modifed FistName", {"text-align":"right"});
    }, 0);
});
```